# Mantle - Transform String to Enum Value

Tags: ios, swift, enums, github-mantle, nsvaluetransformer

In my `User` class, I have defined a `type` property and a `UserType` enum. The `type` property is received as a `String` value in the JSON:

```
{
    "type" : "Admin"
}
```

I would like to use `Mantle` to transform the `String` value into a `UserType` enum object and back to a `String` during serialization and de-serialization, respectively. I have searched through other SO posts and the Mantle documentation but could not get this working properly. Here's my attempt:

```
enum UserType:String
{
    case Normal
    case Admin
}

class User: MTLModel, MTLJSONSerializing
{
    var type:UserType?

    static func JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [NSObject : AnyObject]!
    {
        return ["type" : "type"]
    }

    static func JSONTransformerForKey(key: String!) -> NSValueTransformer!
    {
        if (key == "type")
        {
            return NSValueTransformer(forName: "UserTypeValueTransformer")
        }

        return nil
    }
}

// Custom Transformer
class UserTypeValueTransformer : NSValueTransformer
{
    override func transformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> UserType
    {
        let theValue:String? = (value as? String)

        return ((theValue! == "Admin") ? UserType.Admin : UserType.Normal)
    }

    override func reverseTransformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject?
    {
        let theValue:UserType = (value as! UserType)

        return ((theValue == UserType.Admin) ? "Admin" : "Normal")
    }
}
```

In the code above, I made a custom transformer for converting a `String` to a `UserType` enum value and back. I have overridden `Mantle's` `JSONTransformerForKey` method and specified my custom transformer for the `type` property in order to perform the conversion. When I try to serialize the JSON into a `User` object, I receive this error message:

```
type is not a property of User
```

`type` is clearly a property of the `User` model, but something is going on that is making `Mantle` not able to recognize it.

What should I change in my implementation to get the `String` to enum conversion to work? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go around your problem another way, by using swift enumeration's raw values:

```
enum UserType: String {
    case Normal = "Normal"
    case Admin = "Admin"
}

let string = "Admin"
let value = UserType(rawValue:string) //returns .Admin

let value = UserType.Normal
let string = value.rawValue() //returns "Normal"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was hoping to convert the `String` to an `Enum`, but I don't see why I can't just check against the raw value in the first place.